# Devise crud + namespaces: Pro level :)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, namespaces

- I have `Devise Admin` & `Devise User`;
- I want to use namespaces;

What I want to achieve:

- only devise admin can create devise user
- `registerable` for user is not deleted so that he can edit only page
- user can see only current_user/show page

What I have

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do root :to => 'dashboard#index'
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'user_registrations' }
  devise_for :admins, controllers: { registrations: 'admin_registrations' }
  get 'dashboard/index'
  namespace :admin do
    root 'dashboard#index'
    resources :users
  end
```

user_registration_controller:

```
class UserRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
end
```

users_controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
  def show
    @user =  User.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def edit
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @guest.save
        format.html { redirect_to users_path }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end
  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

+ I have user views as they would be in a normal scaffold.

=> With this setup, anyone can create a user

Any ideas how to solve the questions on top?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use separate user classes with Devise, use roles instead. Devise is only really made to authenticate a single class, while you can hack it into using two classes its a mess. You have to override all the logic of serializing/desearializing users from the session among other things so that devise knows if it should load the Admin or User class.

Its also a bad solution since you are push down a *authorization* problem into the *authentication* layer. Devise's job is to verify that the user is who she/he claims to be, which is no small feat. *Authorization*, on the other hand is rules about what a user can do. "Only admins can create users" is a clear cut *authorization* rule.

The simplest possible role based authorization would be something like this:

```
class AddRoleToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :integer, default: 0
    add_index :users, :role
  end
end

class User
  # ...
  enum role: [:visitor, :admin]
end
```

We use an [enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) which is a single bitmask column to store the users role. Declaring it as an enum column also gives us a few methods for free:

```
user.visitor?
user.admin?
user.admin!
```

So lets create a basic authorization check:

```
def create
  unless current_user.admin?
    redirect_to root_path, status: 401, error: 'You are not authorized to perform this action' and return
  end 

  # ...
end
```

But we don't want to repeat that every time we want to authorize, so lets clean it up:

```
class AuthorizationError < StandardError; end

class ApplicationController

  rescue_from AuthorizationError, with: :deny_access!

  private

    def authorize_admin!
      raise AuthorizationError, unless current_user.admin?
    end

    def deny_access!
      redirect_to root_path, 
           status: 401, 
           error: 'You are not authorized to perform this action'
    end
end
```

So then we can setup the controller with a filter to check the authorization before the action is performed:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_admin!, except: [:show]

  # ... 
end
```

However instead of reinventing the wheel you might want to have a look at [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) or [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) which are solid authorization libraries with great communities. You also might want to look at [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify).

Comment: The authorization based approach you describe is great, however I was assuming to go with different `Devise admin` & `Devise user`, because they will have different associations with other models later on (`scaffold event title admin:references starts_at:date`, `scaffold attendance event:references user:references`, `scaffold appointment admin:references user:references starts_at:date`...

Comment: I really would not advise that, you can setup the relations just fine with a single user class. If you want to call the relation `belongs_to: :admin` you can simply provide the `class_name` option. I think you are underestimating how badly it will mess up you authorization system, you can basically through devise out if you go down that route. Also, its not really recommended to use scaffolding except to prototype in a spike. You will easily outrun yourself by generating way to many actions / views etc which are not properly locked down or tested.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I guess I will somehow try out the 2-devise-model + namespace way and auth gems + one devise model will be next :)..